# Wolfram Alpha will calculate this definite integral but Mathematica won't

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute a definite integral of the form
$$\int_{0.2}^{0.5} \frac{1}{(1 - y)y^2\sqrt{0.5 - y^2 + y^3}}$$
in *Mathematica*. *WolframAlpha* will calculate this but *Mathematica* only outputs the integral in nice text.

This is the command I type in

```
Integrate[1/((1 - y)*y^2*Sqrt[0.5 - y^2 + y^3]), {y, 0.2, 0.5}]
```

Is this wrong? If it helps at all *Mathematica* will on the other hand compute this similar integral with no constant under the square root.
$$\int_{0.2}^{0.5} \frac{1}{(1 - y)y^2\sqrt{- y^2 + y^3}}$$

Comment: use `NIntegrate`. I suppose alpha automatically switches to numeric integration, with mathematica you need to tell it to.  (your second integral has a nice closed form )

Comment: incedentally there is an analytic antiderivative so you can do this: `indef = Integrate[1/((1 - y)*y^2*Sqrt[1/2 - y^2 + y^3]), y];
(indef /. y -> .5 ) - (indef /. y -> .2)  // N // Chop`.  `indef` is such a nasty expression i'm not sure there is any advantage over using `NIntegrate`

Comment: Thank you! I have in fact an analytic solution in a book written in terms of elliptic integrals and was trying to compare the latter with direct numerical integration.

Answer (score 3):

The numerical result you received on *WolframAlpha* is the result of a numerical integration:

```
NIntegrate[1/((1 - y) y^2 Sqrt[0.5 - y^2 + y^3]), {y, 0.2, 0.5}]
```

> ```
> 6.68687
> ```

Or

```
N@Integrate[1/((1 - y)*y^2*Sqrt[0.5 - y^2 + y^3]), {y, 0.2, 0.5}]
```

> ```
> 6.68687
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integrate[1/((1 - y)*y^2*Sqrt[1/2 - y^2 + y^3]), y] // ToRadicals
```

Gives you the symbolic thing